# Meaning of "He could always use a bit of extra money" in the context below

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Phoebus started walking toward the bridge
>   where he planned to meet Esmeralda. Soon he
>   noticed a dark figure creeping behind him in
>   the shadows.
>   “Who’s there?” he called.
>   Claude Frollo, his face hidden by his hood,
>   stepped out of the shadows.
>   “What do you want?” Phoebus asked.
>   “Just to know if you are seeing the young
>   gypsy woman tonight. I mean no harm.”
>   “Why do you want to know, stranger?”
>   “I have my reasons. If you are meeting her,
>   prove it. In return, I will give you a bag of
>   gold coins,” the hooded man said.
>   Phoebus thought about it and smiled.
>   “Very well,” he said. **He could always use a bit
>   of extra money**. “Follow me.”

Sorry maybe this is a simple question but I doubt about its meaning.

Dose it mean one of the following sentences.

1) He could always have money.

2) Everyday He could use a bit of that money.

3) Everyday he could spend a little more money.

second sentence seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3):

It is an idiomatic way of saying that he never had enough money, and always wanted a bit of extra money.

You can say "I could use 10 pounds" to mean "I want 10 pounds" The idea is that if someone is rich and have enough money, then the can't use any more.

Comment: Lots of thanks. So dose it simply mean: He never had enough money to spend or he always wanted to have more money.

Comment: It means that he never had enough money and always wanted a bit of extra money. But it doesn't mean that he is very poor.